# How to load the large data into a data table in a quicker way

Tags: jquery, node.js, mongodb, datatables

Actually I'm getting the distinct client_ip list into a getcsv file by querying mongodb.Later I'm calling the getcsv file as shown below:

```
d3.csv('getcsv', function(data) {

        var columns = ['Upload-Clients']
        tabulate(data, columns)

        $('#example').DataTable({
        "lengthMenu": [[ 15, 25, -1], [15, 25, "All"]]

        });
      });

      $("#ip").val('');

    });
```

And now I'm trying to load the data of getcsv file into a data table.Actually in getcsv file,I have nearly 68,000 records.For loading the data into the data table,it is taking nearly one minute span.Then how can we load the entire data with in a short time span.

You can check this url for index.html file and getcsv file  http://plnkr.co/edit/AAiX3V5nL6q44BHkKrsj?p=preview

Can anyone please give me a suggestion regarding this issue ...

Comment: I got stucked over here.Please help me out in resolving this issue.

Comment: You shouldn't use a huge CSV because you can't paginate it without load it entirely. I can suggest to import the data into a DB and do server side pagination.

Comment: Ya I already have data in the mongodb.Can u please suggest me how to do server side pagination using mongodb and node.js.

Comment: Query the collection adding `limit` and `skip` options example: http://www.hacksparrow.com/mongodb-pagination-using-skip.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur info.